# I am getting a ValueError: "ValueError: Number of labels=16512 does not match number of samples=16339"

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, valueerror

I'm experimenting with machine learning and I am new to it, so I do not know why I am getting this error:
`ValueError: Number of labels=16512 does not match number of samples=16339` I searched it up and nothing helped me. Could someone help me with this? I have no idea why it does this and I think I did everything right. I am trying to predict the house prices with this.

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

train = pd.read_csv('housing.csv')
X = train.drop(columns=["median_house_value", "ocean_proximity"])
y = train["median_house_value"]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, test_size = 0.2)

model = DecisionTreeClassifier()
X_train = X_train.dropna()
y_train = y_train.dropna()

model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

This is my error message:

````
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-4691a6b66d80> in <module>
     17 y_train = y_train.dropna()
     18 
---> 19 model.fit(X_train, y_train)

c:\users\zhang\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\_classes.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, check_input, X_idx_sorted)
    888         """
    889 
--> 890         super().fit(
    891             X, y,
    892             sample_weight=sample_weight,

c:\users\zhang\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\_classes.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, check_input, X_idx_sorted)
    270 
    271         if len(y) != n_samples:
--> 272             raise ValueError("Number of labels=%d does not match "
    273                              "number of samples=%d" % (len(y), n_samples))
    274         if not 0 <= self.min_weight_fraction_leaf <= 0.5:

ValueError: Number of labels=16512 does not match number of samples=16339```
````

Comment: Did you check whether the shapes of X_train and y_train are similar? Looks like some data points in your data set don't have labels.

Comment: Ok, I checked the shape, and it returned (16348, 8)
(16512,), I really don't know what happened

Comment: Are you assigning after dropping the column from the dataframe here:
X = train.drop(columns=["median_house_value", "ocean_proximity"])
y = train["median_house_value"]

Comment: What do you mean assigning @picmate涅

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood something. Please disregard the earlier comment. Is there a possibility to access the 'housing.csv' data set? Could really find out what's going on.

Comment: Yeah sure here it is: https://www.kaggle.com/camnugent/california-housing-prices @picmate涅

Comment: Just posted an answer; had no issues with the data set with the way I followed (very close to what you did). Thought dropna is the issue but that wasn't an issue either. Let me know if you run into any other issues.

Comment: I suspect you are not dropping the same amount of rows when you execute, `X_train = X_train.dropna()` and `y_train = y_train.dropna()`.   Try dropping NaN in the dataframe, train, before creating X and y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the following? I didn't have issues with this method:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

data = pd.read_csv('housing.csv')

prices = data['median_house_value']
features = data.drop(['median_house_value', 'ocean_proximity'], axis = 1)
```

---

```
prices.shape
(20640,)

features.shape
(20640, 8)
```

---

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features, prices, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

X_train = X_train.dropna()
y_train = y_train.dropna()
```

---

```
y_train.shape
(16512,)

X_train.shape
(16512, 8)
```

---

```
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=None,
                       max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=None,
                       min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
                       min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
                       min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, presort=False,
                       random_state=None, splitter='best')
```